# How to filter date According to Today Current Date in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to filter date in Django according to current date, But it's displaying mr `0` results, Please let me know Where I am mistaking.

Hers is my `models.py` file...

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=True, blannk=True)
    customer_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blannk=True)
```

here is my `views.py` file, where i am trying to get date according to today date...

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time, date

def getdate(request):
    today=datetime.today()
    customer_data = Customer.objects.filter(customer_date=today).count()
    print(customer_data, "Count Values")
```

Answer (score 3):

I see some issue in your date filter. When you do:

```
datetime.datetime.today()
#2020-11-04 10:57:22.214606
```

this give complete timestamp.
However you want to do date match only.so, try something like code.

```
today = datetime.today().date()
#today=datetime.today()
customer_data = Customer.objects.filter(customer_date__date=today).count()
```

hope this may help your query.

Answer (score 0):

I saw you mistyped blank as blannk